# Echo the results of query based on its index

Tags: php, mysql, echo

This is pretty basic but I can't seem to get it to work

I have this query

```
$people = "SELECT name FROM people";
$people = mysql_query($people) or die(mysql_error());
$row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people);
$totalRows_people = mysql_num_rows($people);
```

I can echo the first result of this query with

```
<?php echo $row_people['name']; ?>
```

I could also create a loop and echo all the results.

But I really want to echo the results individually based on its index.

I have tried this, but it does not work.

```
<?php echo $row_people['name'][2]; ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch them by their index using a WHERE clause.

```
$people = sprintf("SELECT name FROM people WHERE index='%d'", $index);
```

If you want to query all rows, you could store them into an array while looping over them:

```
$people = "SELECT name FROM people";
$people = mysql_query($people) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_people = mysql_num_rows($people);
$rows_people = array();
while($row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people))
{
    $rows_people[] = $row_people;
}
```

You might want to add the primary key to the returned fields and use it as the array index probably.

Answer (score 0):

You can ORDER them by their index and then use a loop.

```
$people = "SELECT name FROM people ORDER by index";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_data_seek on the result object to seek to a particular row. E.g., to get the name value from row 2:

```
mysql_data_seek($people, 2);
$row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people);
echo $row_people['name'];
```

If you're doing this a lot it will be easier to gather all the rows together in a single array at the start:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($people)) $data[] = $row;
```

This way you can fetch any cells in the results trivially:

```
echo $data[2]['name'];
```